# RecyclerView : where should i put this method?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I tried to remove one item using:

```
if (paymentType.getPaymentId()==2002) {
    recyclerAdapter.deleteItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
}
```

on my fragment activity,

and this is the method on my adapter (one adapter for many RecyclerView)

```
public void deleteItem(int position){
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, data.size());
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

but I got error like this:

> Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

Thanks.

Comment: When you know the **PaymentId** before loading to RecyclerView , then don't add the item to arraylist

Comment: i can't do that because my adapter also using by another RecyclerView, that's why i asked where should i put my code

Comment: After getting the response from the web services filter based on PaymentId and add to arrayList and pass this to the adapter, it wont effect the new instance of same adapter which you are using in other places.

Comment: thanks @bk7 ,u open the way for me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

This is because you call notify method multiple times. You only need to notify than an item is removed in RecyclerView Adapter. So, only call `notifyItemRemoved()` in your method. Like this:

```
public void deleteItem(int position) {
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Comment: i have 5 item on my recycler view and paymentId=2002 on my 2nd item. if i'm using this method, item no 2 - 5 disappear

Comment: When you need to remove multiple items in non-sequential position, then you just need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Never use `deleteItem` to delete multiple items.

Comment: `i have 5 item on my recycler view and paymentId=2002 on my 2nd item. if i'm using this method, item no 2 - 5 disappear`, then you need to check the item by the id before deleting it. Use the position only to notify the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to gone that item. This is best practice

```
if (paymentType.getPaymentId()==2002) {

   rowRootLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}else{

   rowRootLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```